# Silverlight 3.0 Slider Move in increments of N

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, controls, slider, increment

I was wondering if anybody knows how to move the slider in increments of 50 or more.

0 - 50 - 100 - 150 - 200 ETC....

I'm implementing a slider to filter some grid results.

```
<Slider x:Name="PointsSlider" Width="350" Height="Auto" ValueChanged="PointsSlider_ValueChanged"
                                Minimum="25" Maximum="3000" LargeChange="50"></Slider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean programmatically do the equivalent of clicking either side of the slider's "thumb", or something else?

If so: To emulate the click just set the slider's *Value* member to the current value +/- the  desired increment.